# How can I send two values with one DropDownList / send 3 values with 2 input form ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 tables, a book table and a bookshelf table. In the book table I have entities:

```
id   title      category
1   GoodNature  Science
```

whereas in my bookshelf table I have entities:

```
id  book_id category    bookshelf_name
1   1       Science      A11
```

bookshelf.cs (Model)

```
public partial class bookshelf

{   

 public int id { get; set; }
 public int book_id { get; set; }
 public string category { get; set; }
 public string bookshelf_name { get; set; }
 public List BookCollection { get; set; }

}
```

BookShelfController.cs (Controller)

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  master_bookshelf bookShe = new master_bookshelf();
  bookShe.BookCollection = db.master_book.ToList<master_book>();
  return View(bookShe);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateShelf(master_bookshelf Shelf)
{
  db.master_bookshelf.Add(Shelf);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "BookShelf");
}
```

BookShelf.cshtml (View)

```
...
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="CreateShelf">
...
<td>Book Name</td>
<td>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.book_id, new SelectList(Model.HadiahCollection, "id", "titile"), "Select"
, new { @class = "form-control select2", @style = "width: 100%;", @required = "required" })
</td> <tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookshelf_name" required></td>
</tr>
...
```

How do I fill in the category column in the bookshelf table by simply having an 2 input form that is the dropdownlist for select book name and then send id to book_id and the text input form for the bookshelf name?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the key (book.id) from the select list choice, query for the category by querying the book by id. Are you using entity framework?

Comment: When they submit the form, get the category using entity framework. Something like: bookshelf shelf= context.bookshelf.Find(selected_bookshelf.id) then category=shelf.category